# Export text file by some terms

Tags: ubuntu, text

I have in.txt file with over 10000 line, some text in this file between bract like ( this text ) and the text out the bract not export, i want to export all text between ( ) to out.txt, but provided that under 140 letters if the letters over 140 letters don't export it, and every text exported in new line  out.txt .
I wan't script to do that in ubuntu, and the text written by non latin letters (utf-8).
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the text between parentheses can't itself contain parentheses, and that you mean under or equal to 140 characters, try

```
grep -Po '(?<=\().{1,140}?(?=\))' in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Thank you steeldriver, it's work, Best Regards.

Comment: Please can you change this code or give me new code to remove any line containt one or more of this symbole ( ? , [ , ] ,  - ).

Comment: @silver you can try replacing `.{1,140}` by `[^[\]-]{1,140}`

Comment: to remove any line containt symbol: grep -v '[\:\?\*\«\»\،\-]' in.txt > out.txt